# Store marker.getTag() to a string - android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

What I am trying to do is that if I clicked a specific marker, it should get the tag and store it in the global string. Then I will click this button which will tell (show a Toast) if the tag is the same to what I typed in my AutoCompleteTextView.

My onMarkerClick codes:

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        tag = marker.getTag().toString();
        return false;
    }
```

This is the marker that I put in my Google Maps which i set a tag called "bike"

```
public void espana(){

    LatLng espana = new LatLng(14.612056, 120.995471);
    MarkerOptions espanaMarker = new MarkerOptions();
    espanaMarker.position(espana);
    espanaMarker.title("Espana");
    espanaMarker.snippet("Fare rate: 8-25 pesos");

    mCurrLocationMarker = map.addMarker(espanaMarker);
    mCurrLocationMarker.setTag("bike");

    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
            new LatLng(14.611319, 120.994752),
            new LatLng(14.612855, 120.996404)
    )
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.RED)
    );
}
```

My codes in Button onClick:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.text_category);

            if (textView.getText().equals(tag)){

                Toast.makeText(this, "This is my message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is wrong with my code and it's in my onclick button. I forgot to add .toString() in my 'if' statement. It does not read the textView as a string that is why the program skips the 'if' statement.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.text_category);

            if (textView.getText().toString().equals(tag)){

                Toast.makeText(this, "This is my message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}
```